# Add button to print table to printer in bonfire codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, printing

i'm new in codeigniter and bonfire, and i'm very noob at this, but i want to know how can i add button to print my table to printer or pdf file. i tried using `window.print()`, it works but it didn't load css or table's style. i know i must load css file inside javascript, then i use this code :

```
function printContent(id){
str=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
newwin=window.open('','printwin','left=100,top=100,width=400,height=400')
newwin.document.write('<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<TITLE>Print Page</TITLE>\n')
newwin.document.write('<script>\n')
newwin.document.write('function chkstate(){\n')
newwin.document.write('if(document.readyState=="complete"){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.close()\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('else{\n')
newwin.document.write('setTimeout("chkstate()",2000)\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('function print_win(){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.print();\n')
newwin.document.write('chkstate();\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('<\/script>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()">\n')
newwin.document.write(str)
newwin.document.write('</BODY>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HTML>\n')
newwin.document.close()
}
```

but i didn't know where is bonfire store their css file that i must to include, i tried include this `newwin.document.write('<?php echo Assets::css; ?>\n')` , it didn't work at all, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you must load your js in head in Bonfire you can add your js 

Path:-public\themes\default\header.php

Here is the file where you need to add your js.

```
Assets::add_js('bootstrap.min.js','your_js_file');
```

If you face any problem then please let me know.